# Deployment plan for .net core application along with environment variables

Tags: c#, .net, iis, asp.net-core, octopus-deploy

I am currently working on .net core web application deployment in multiple environment - Testing, UAT, PROD, etc.

As per documentations says, we should have environment specific `appsettings.{environment}.json` files so when we deploy application onto specific environment, respective file will be used.

I believe we use **IIS** -> **configuration Editor** to set `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` variable.

However, I am unable to find, how can we do this thru deployment plan without going onto server.

Currently I am using Octopus deployment tool.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to store *environment specific* settings in ***Octopus Deploy*** (in **scoped variables**) rather than in your .json files which will
 - or should even - be under source control.

Say your `appsettings.json` looks like this

```
{
 "weatherApiUrl": "dev.weather.com",
 "weatherApiKey": "DEV1234567",
 "tempImageFolder": "C:\temp\img"
}
```

In your Project Variables you specify the *weatherApiUrl* variable and set it to `dev.weather.com` scoped to Development, `test.weather.com` scoped to Test, etc.

In your Process, in the Deploy step, goto **Configure Features** and enable `JSON configuration variables`. Now the Deploy step will have an extra section named *JSON configuration variables*, specify the name of your config file there, `appsettings.json` and off you go.

More information here: [JSON Configuration Variables Feature](https://octopus.com/docs/guides/deploying-asp.net-core-web-applications/json-configuration-variables-feature)